# Prove that $A,B$ have a common eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, soft-question, education

Let $A,B$ be $2\times2$ real matrices satisfying $\det(A)=\det(B)=1$ and $$\text{tr}(A)>2 , \text{tr}(B)>2, \text{tr}(ABA^{-1}B^{-1})=2$$
Prove that A,B have a common eigenvector.

Comment: I found that eigenvalue A and B is not "1" and they are diagonalizable and matrix (ABA^(-1)B^(-1)) has a eigenvalue 1,1 but i can't talk about the degree of this eigenvalue and ....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible approach:

1. Show that each of $A$ and $B$ has distinct real positive eigenvalues.
2. Hence $A$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb R$. By a change of basis, we may assume that $A=\operatorname{diag}(p,\frac1p)$ for some $p>0$. Let $B=\pmatrix{a&b\\ c&d}$ in this basis.
3. Use the given conditions and the assumption in (2) to prove that $bc=0$, i.e. $B$ is upper or lower triangular. Now the rest is straightforward.

Comment: An idea: Let $X = ABA^{-1}B^{-1}$. Then by the Cayley-Hamilton Theorem, X satisfies the polynomial $f(t) = t^{2} - \text{Tr}(X)t + \det X$. Using the fact that $\det X = 1$ and $\text{Tr}(X) =2$, it follows that $0 = X^{2} - 2X + I = (X - I)^{2}$. It follows then that the matrix $M = X - I$  has characteristic polynomial $C_{M}(t) = t^{2}$.

Comment: thank you @user1551... the best way to prove it!! although number 1 and 2 is easy to get, but number 3 is not as trivial as them... just in case to prove number (3) i knew from condition which $AB-BA$ is a nilpotent matrix ,either in new basis you'd mentioned... so from this i found out bc=0 ... i want to know was it the way you solved?

Comment: thank you @akech for idea. actually one of my approach to solve, was the way you'd mentioned. but i can't go further...can you please elaborate?

Comment: @vahid_shahverdi Try to express $\operatorname{tr}(ABA^{-1}B^{-1})$ directly in terms of $b,c,p$.